# How to get a single row from a pair

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Here I want only one row to be displayed.

Here's the long piece of inefficient code that works.

```
Select T1.FacFirstName + ' ' + T1.FacLastName AS FacultyName, T1.FacDept,
T2.FacFirstName + ' ' + T2.FacLastName AS ColleagueName, 
T2.FacDept AS ColleagueDept, 
T1.CourseNo, T1.AVERAGEGRADE AS FACULTYAVGGRADE, 
T2.AVERAGEGRADE AS COLLEAGUEAVGGRADE
FROM    (SELECT FACULTY.FACNO, FACULTY.FACFIRSTNAME, FACULTY.FACLASTNAME, 
        OFFERING.COURSENO, FACULTY.FACDEPT, AVG(ENROLLMENT.ENRGRADE) AS 
        AVERAGEGRADE
        FROM FACULTY, OFFERING, ENROLLMENT 
        WHERE FACULTY.FACNO = OFFERING.FACNO AND ENROLLMENT.OFFERNO = 
        OFFERING.OFFERNO
        GROUP BY ENROLLMENT.OFFERNO, FACULTY.FACNO, FACULTY.FACFIRSTNAME, 
        FACULTY.FACLASTNAME, OFFERING.COURSENO, FACULTY.FACDEPT) T1, 
        (SELECT FACULTY.FACNO, FACULTY.FACFIRSTNAME, FACULTY.FACLASTNAME, 
        OFFERING.COURSENO, FACULTY.FACDEPT, AVG(ENROLLMENT.ENRGRADE) AS 
        AVERAGEGRADE
        FROM FACULTY, OFFERING, ENROLLMENT 
        WHERE FACULTY.FACNO = OFFERING.FACNO AND ENROLLMENT.OFFERNO = 
        OFFERING.OFFERNO
        GROUP BY ENROLLMENT.OFFERNO, FACULTY.FACNO, FACULTY.FACFIRSTNAME, 
        FACULTY.FACLASTNAME, OFFERING.COURSENO, FACULTY.FACDEPT) T2
where T1.CourseNo = T2.CourseNo and T1.FacDept != T2.FacDept
```

PS: I'm new to SQL and StackOverflow, so suggestions in both are well appreciated. TIA.

Comment: You can use  `SELECT TOP 1`

Comment: No, I cannot do that as the code won't be robust, when there are multiple CourseNo popping up.

Comment: So which row you would be preferring , either u can add one more condition to get one selected row. Or u can use `OFFSET  0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY `

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(SQL.110).aspx

Comment: What I'd ideally want is one row for each CourseNo that comes as result of the sub-query. Any row is fine. I'm not sure OFFSET will work as well cause, if there are 3 Faculties offering the same CourseNo, the results would be misleading.

Comment: Can you add some information about the data you're querying (schema of tables, primary keys, etc.)

Comment: Are you attempting to identify all `FACULTY` who offer a particular `OFFERING` along with the average `ENRGRADE` for all enrolled in that faculty's offering? And there could be `N` faculty members offering the same `COURSENO`? All output on a single row?